# Recommended approach for creating custom HTML objects in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, object, element, customization

I am creating a webpage consisting of several objects. Each of these objects are similar; they have a  drawing graphics , a few 's, a few buttons etc. Also, each object has some functions. These objects are created by js code.
What is the best approach here?
Is it possible to define a class that acts as a custom HTML-element, and also has its own methods?
Or is there some other way?

Up until now I've been creating these objects be calling a static function with some parameters, in order to set up all these elements and functionality. But the code becomes messy and hard to read, the more functionality I add.

I also wonder if there's a way to use a HTML file for each of these objects, and just populate the pre-defined elements of the file upon creation?

Comment: I feel like you may find [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) delightful.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a couple of short examples of your code.

Comment: In addition have a look into [_Web Components_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components) and [_Custom_Elements_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements).

Comment: It was a missprint. All the objects do the same things and have the same functionality, but they are fed with different data upon creation. The canvas draws a chart from the data. In each of these objetcts there are 2 checkboxes, enableing / disabeling some data in the charts. There is also a button that opens some settings for the object.

Comment: Which technology are you going to choose? `Web Components`/`Custom Elements` or a component-based approach of good old pure DOM-scripting? Regardless off technology/tooling the audience at some point needs to see a minimum code base consisting of markup and JS. What have you got so far?

Comment: The reason I did not include any code is that it is not offering any clarification without further describing the context. It is just a long for loop, iterating over an array. For each iteration it goes through a process of creating a bunch of HTML elements (document.createElement) and drawing a chart on a canvas. I guess this is what you mean by "component-based approach of good old pure DOM-scripting" The code is not very clean and mature yet, as I am still experimenting and looking for beast approach to the problem. However I see "web components" (Extending HTMLElement), is one way..

Comment: @Peter thanks for your replies. No more questions. I went on with the webcomponents approach.

Answer (score 1):

From the OP's comment ...

> The reason I did not include any code is that it is not offering any clarification without further describing the context. It is just a long for loop, iterating over an array. For each iteration it goes through a process of creating a bunch of HTML elements (document.createElement) and drawing a chart on a canvas. I guess this is what you mean by "component-based approach of good old pure DOM-scripting" The code is not very clean and mature yet, as I am still experimenting and looking for beast approach to the problem. However I see "web components" (Extending HTMLElement), is one way.

The good old DOM-scripting can be combined with abstraction. One could choose a class implementation, and a first code iteration then relates markup and code by identifying a component via a custom `data-*` attribute like e.g. `data-chart`.

Though it's still far away from *Web Components*, it does already look somehow close to it; which should be of no surprise, because *Web Components* offers a standardized and more convenient API to a pattern (abstraction and rendering of re-usable components) which did pop up already more than 20 years ago.

```js
class Chart {
  #root;

  #dataUrl;
  #chartData;

  constructor(root) {
    this.compile(root);
  }
  // prototypal methods

  compile(root) {
    if (
      root?.matches?.('[data-chart]') && (
        root.matches('[data-chart-data]') ||
        root.matches('[data-chart-data-url]')
      )
    ) {
      this.#root = root;

      // e.g. for fetching chart data upon which canvas drawing takes place.
      this.#dataUrl = root.dataset.chartDataUrl;

      // e.g. provided chart data upon which canvas drawing takes place.
      this.#chartData = root.dataset.chartData;

      const elmCanvas = this.#root.querySelector('canvas');

      console.log(
        { elmCanvas, dataUrl: this.#dataUrl, chartData: this.#chartData }
      );
    } else {
      throw ReferenceError(
        'The argument of `compile` does not match the chart criteria.'
      );
    }
  }
  // - more implementations for e.g. drawing on canvas
  //   and/or fetching chart data from the provided url.
}

function initializeCharts() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-chart]')
    .forEach(root => new Chart(root));
}
initializeCharts();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
[data-chart] {
  width: 33%;
}
[data-chart] figure {
  background-color: #fc0;
}
[data-chart] canvas {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0fc;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  width: 65%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article
  data-chart
  data-chart-data="[{&quot;point&quot;:{3,8}}]"
  data-chart-data-url="https://fetch.mychart.data"
>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Settings</legend>

    <label>
      <span>Data Foo</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Data Bar</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter" />
    </label>

    <button type="button" name="settings" title="Component Settings">
      <span>Component Settings</span>
    </button>
  </fieldset>

  <figure>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <figcaption>brief chart description</figcaption>
  </figure>
</article>
```